# Change of RAD Date picker UI on selection of value from combobox ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, telerik, raddatepicker

i have one combo box which has three values blue,green,yellow based on the value selected i need to have a rad date picker.

if i select blue and yellow from combo box i need to get the date picker UI in **dd/MM/yyyy** format.

if i select green from combo **i need to get the date picker UI in MM/yyyy** format.

I am new to this i don't know how to implement this and how to bind this later.
please also let me know how to save date field in db for MM/yyyy format.Is it either smalldatetime datatype or string?
Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach I can think of is to change the date format of the **picker**  through the **DateFormat** and/or **DisplayDateFormat** properties (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-dateinput-formatting-values.html) in the **SelectedIndexChanged** event of the **combobox** (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-server-side-selectedindexchanged.html) Something like this should do the tridk

```
protected void RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadDatePicker1.DateInput.DisplayDateFormat = "dd / MM / yyyy";
    RadDatePicker1.DateInput.DateFormat = "dd / MM / yyyy";
}
```

On saving in a database - get the value of the datepicker and format it

```
DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

or

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", picker.SelectedDate);
```

would be two basic examples